# How to increase the thickness of the extrude geometry along x and z axis - Three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I had created a shape using **extrude geometry ,** and now with the extrude settings i need to increase the thickness  i had used **`bevelThickness`** it increases the **thickness** along **y axis** , but need to increase it along **x and z axis.**

Here my working [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Roobena/cqgt1hra/1/)

Below is my code for extrude settings ,

```
var extrusionSettings = {
            curveSegments:5,
            steps: 10,
            amount: 10,
            bevelEnabled: true,
            bevelThickness: 120,
            bevelSize: 0,
            bevelSegments: 8,
            material: 0,
            extrudeMaterial: 1
        };

        var geometry1 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape1, extrusionSettings );

        var materialLeft = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xd6d6d6,// red  
            transparent:true,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            ambient: 0xea6767,
            opacity:-0.5
        });
        var materialRight = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xcc49c3,//violet                
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            ambient: 0xcc49c3
        });         

        var materials = [  materialLeft, materialRight                               
                            ];

        var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
        var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material );          
        object.add( mesh1 );
        object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;

        scene.add( object );
```

Below is sample image
[image]

is there any setting to increase it ? Can any one guide me ?

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html for how to extrude a shape with a hole in it.

Comment: @WestLangley [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Roobena/2g7wt4gk/) is my another fiddle which i had used the hole for extrude shape , but for creating this need 2 path values ( 1 for the shape and another for the hole ) , but in my process i will be getting only one path vale ( the outer path shape ) is that possible to generate the another inner path ( hole )

Comment: You have to create the hole path yourself... Also, spend time experimenting with every parameter value in your demo and make sure you understand what it represents. Looking at your code, it appears that you do not understand everything yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i did the trick to fix it, What i did is just i cloned a Mesh add added the position to cloned mesh, so i got the wall nearby another inner wall, by this way i have added multiple clone with the loop, multiple inner wall nearby other created the wall thickens,

Demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqgt1hra/4/)

```
//outer wall mesh 
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material );
  object.add( mesh1 );

  var mesh_arr=new Array();
  for(i=0.1;i<15;i++)
  {

      //cloned mesh,add position to the cloning mesh
      mesh_arr[i] = mesh1.clone();
      mesh_arr[i].position.set(i,i,i);
      mesh_arr[i].updateMatrix();
      object.add( mesh_arr[i] );

  }
```

[image: Result]